# graph figure in boxes

Tags: floats, diagrams, wrapfigure

I want to construct several columns of boxes in latex of which one of them will contain a graph. I thought about drawing the graph using the tikz package which I have novice experience in, but Im wondering how I can construct boxes around the figure and additional boxes which will explain properties of the graph. The ideal would be to have three squares. One smaller square denoting the id, number of vertices for the graph, larger square for the graph itself and a smaller square box denoting associated properties of the graph.

The graph would look something like this for reference:

[image: example of a graph, 1 vertex]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->,>=stealth',
    shorten >=1pt,
    auto,
    node distance=3cm, 
    thick,
    main node/.style{circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
    framed,
] 

  \node[main node] (1) {1}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
```

However I would like to expand the size of the box and to construct two additional boxes.

Comment: All I have now is 

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
                    thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},framed]

  \node[main node] (1) {1};

\end{tikzpicture}

but the frame is too small. Also neeed to add two separate boxes. One before the graph picture and another after.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Also, the solution may be dependent on the packages that you are using.

Comment: @PeterGrill yes, thats good advice. I might recreate a similar question in the future with a fully compatible MWE.